# Passing information from form to form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

My setup. I have a form that searches through a table names Students containing student information, ID, Name, Home Room, etc. The form text boxes are parameters in a search Query, which then puts its information into a Multiple Items subform.

My goal is to add a button beside each student record on that subform that will do two simultaneous things:

1) Add the student ID to an Incident Occurences table.
2) Open a form to the record just added and edit the values in other fields for that record.

For example, if John Doe decides to draw on his desk, a teacher will be able to search for John Doe, click a button. His student ID goes to the Incident Occurences table, and a form opens up where the teacher can edit the fields for the new record, to add information like what happened, time, etc.

I know how to open a form to a specific record, using the form filter. I also know how to add the student ID to the form. What I don't know is how to get the ID of the record added with an Append Query.

Thanks.

Comment: This can be done.  Can you edit your post and give some more details? Perhaps an example and the names of the forms.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in VBA.  Run the Append query via code, and then open that table and do a MoveLast.  You can grab the ID of the last record that matches your student.  You can't get the ID of a record until the record is written, so I think that's the only way to do it.

Comment: My concern with doing that is concurrency. Two users trying to enter the different data for the same student. Could there be a conflict?
Example, you and I are recording an incident for John Doe. We select him, and adds two IDs to the incident table. Then we each get the last record, which would be only one of ours, not the correct respective one.

Comment: Unless two teachers are entering the exact same thing you should have no problems.  Access is first come first serve so if teacher A creates a file for Johnny when Teacher B does too, then whoever clicked the add button first will get the first record.

Comment: If you were really worried about this, you could add a separate column that adds a value when a user opens a record for that student with and then another column when that form/record closes.  You can do that with `Form_Load()` and `Form_Close()`

Comment: What TKEyi60 said.  We're talking about milliseconds here.  What are the odds that 2 teachers enter a record about the same student within a timeframe that short?  I've done this in apps with hundreds of users and never once had a problem.